# Rubygem creation ... I have pushed a new gem but the Source Code link is missing

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created and pushed a new gem for the first time in several years. I am a newbie in the Gem business.

I followed the various instructions and the gem was successfully pushed. Here is the link to new gem:

https://rubygems.org/gems/yequel

The only problem is that the 'Source Code' link does not appear on the above page. I have attached the gemspec that was used to push the gem.

Please help me identify what I am missing.

Thanks ... Al

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'yequel/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "yequel"
  spec.version       = Yequel::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Al Kivi"]
  spec.email         = ["al.kivi@vizi.ca"]

  spec.summary       = %q{Provides a sequel style ORM layer for YAML::Store}
  spec.description   = %q{Yequel provides a sequel style with basic features to access YAML::Store tables.  Its target audience is application developers who require light weight alternative to SQL databases.}
  spec.homepage      = "https://rubygems.org/profiles/vizi_master"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org by setting 'allowed_push_host', or
  # delete this section to allow pushing this gem to any host.
  #if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    #spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
  #else
    #raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
  #end

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.11"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "hash_dot"
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "will_paginate"

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The Source link isn’t specified in the gemspec, only the homepage (which could point to a code repository).

If you want to set the the source link you need to do it on the Rubygems site. Sign into rubygems.org, and go to https://rubygems.org/gems/yequel/edit (there should be a link to this page from your gem’s page in the “Links” section, if you are signed in). From there you should be able to set the Source Code URL, along with a range of other URLs.

Comment: Your feedback was quite helpful. I had forgotten that Github updates and Rubygems updates were separate processes. For some strange reason, I thought that the Rubygems update would automatically create the Github repository.